# Distributing published papers if I am the first author

Tags: journals, copyright, collaboration

In some interviews for industry positions, I have been asked about my prior (applied math) research experience and to go into detail about the models I have constructed. After I gave him a high-level overview, the interviewer asked that I send him the paper so he can see some minute details. The paper is published in a Springer journal and costs 39.95 to see without journal subscription. My questions are

> 1. As the first author of the paper, am I legally allowed I send him a downloaded version of the paper over email?
> 2. If not, am I legally allowed to send my personal copy of the manuscript (i.e. the version I submitted to Springer)?

N.B. the paper is not on the arXiv.

Comment: You've read the copyright agreement you signed when the paper was accepted, right?  What does it say about this?  That's the authoritative source; other answers will just be guesses.

Comment: Regardless of the specific language of the copyright agreement, just give them a copy of the paper.  Sharing copies of one's own papers has been standard academic practice forever.

Answer (score 3):

Different publishers have different guidelines, but I *think* they all allow your first case. For example, [Elsevier's author rights page](https://www.elsevier.com/about/company-information/policies/copyright#Author%20rights) states:

> Authors transfer copyright to the publisher as part of a journal publishing agreement, but have the right to:
>
> - Share their article for Personal Use, Internal Institutional Use and Scholarly Sharing purposes, with a DOI link to the version of record on ScienceDirect (and with the Creative Commons CC-BY-NC- ND license for author manuscript versions)
> - ...

If you're worried, I do recommend checking each publisher's page to verify your rights.